# Running the Tensorflow2 upgrade Script triggers an encoding error

Tags: encoding, jupyter-notebook, upgrade, tensorflow2.x

I am currently trying to upgrade a script to be compatible with **tensorflow2** by using the jupyter notebook that is provided in https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade, so that I can run it in google colab,  however when I run this cell (from an Anaconda environment in windows):

```
!tf_upgrade_v2 \
  --infile D:/Multiclass.py\
  --outfile /tmp/upgraded_Multiclass_CNN_V01_31012020Copy.py
```

I get an encoding error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\programdata\miniconda3\envs\env_dlexp1\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "d:\programdata\miniconda3\envs\env_dlexp1\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\Env_DLexp1\Scripts\tf_upgrade_v2.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\tools\compatibility\tf_upgrade_v2_main.py", line 139, in main
    args.input_file, output_file, upgrade)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\tools\compatibility\tf_upgrade_v2_main.py", line 40, in process_file
    upgrader.process_file(in_filename, out_filename)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\tools\compatibility\ast_edits.py", line 900, in process_file
    temp_file)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\tools\compatibility\ast_edits.py", line 958, in process_opened_file
    lines = in_file.readlines()
  File "d:\programdata\miniconda3\envs\env_dlexp1\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 14: character maps to <undefined>
```

I would normally change the encoding to **`utf-8`** by doing this:  `open(path, mode, encoding='UTF8')`
,but in this case I am clueless. I am not a programmer, so my proficiency is very limited. Please help me understand this error.

Comment: same here, sadly no response here yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try editing `with open` in line 918 of function `process_file` in ast_edits.py and specify encoding='utf-8', so that in the function `process_opened_file` the file can be read with utf-8.